# Cannot use sessionfilter parameter in my other classes

Tags: java, authentication, automation, automated-tests, rest-assured

I'm trying to create a cookie-based session with RestAssured. Then I'm trying to add a comment on my jira ticket which I created before. Seems like I can create session id with method Authenticate(), but I cannot use that session in my other methods which are in different java files. Seems like ilter(Authenticator.session) is not working in my other methods, because in console I'm getting error

> You do not have permission to create attachments for this issue

but when I run all these under main method in a single java class, it works properly.

```
public class Authenticator {
public static SessionFilter session = new SessionFilter();

public static void Authenticate(){
    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8080";


    String authenticationResponse = given().header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .filter(session)
            .body(JiraInputs.auth())
            .when().post("/rest/auth/1/session")
            .then().log().all().extract().response().asString();


}


public class AddAttachment {

public static void addAttachment(){

    // Add Attachment
    RestAssured.baseURI="http://localhost:8080";
    System.out.println(Authenticator.session.getSessionId());

    given().header("X-Atlassian-Token","no-check")
            .header("Content-Type","multipart/form-data")
            .multiPart("file",new File("src/test/java/Repo/jira"))
            .pathParam("id","10000").filter(Authenticator.session).when().
            post("/rest/api/2/issue/{id}/attachments")
            .then().log().all().extract().response().asString();
    System.out.println(Authenticator.session.getSessionId());



}
}


public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    // Authenticate
    Authenticator.Authenticate();
    AddAttachment.addAttachment();

}
}
```

```
 {
        "errorMessages": [
            "You do not have permission to create attachments for this issue."
        ],
        "errors": {
            
        }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try static setting `RestAssured.filters(new SessionFilter());`?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get it :(, can you give an example in a little code section ? So that I can implement in my code. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Static setting can solve this. `RestAssured.filters(new SessionFilter());`

Remove `public static SessionFilter session = new SessionFilter();`

```
public class Authenticator {

  public static void Authenticate(){
    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8080";

    String authenticationResponse = given().header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .body(JiraInputs.auth())
            .when().post("/rest/auth/1/session")
            .then().log().all().extract().response().asString();
  }
}


public class AddAttachment {

  public static void addAttachment(){

    // Add Attachment
    RestAssured.baseURI="http://localhost:8080"; 

    given().header("X-Atlassian-Token","no-check")
            .header("Content-Type","multipart/form-data")
            .multiPart("file",new File("src/test/java/Repo/jira"))
            .pathParam("id","10000")
    .when()
            .post("/rest/api/2/issue/{id}/attachments")
            .then().log().all().extract().response().asString();
  }
}


public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestAssured.filters(new SessionFilter());
        Authenticator.Authenticate();
        AddAttachment.addAttachment();
    }
}
```